# Привет, помогите написать (исправить мой) код, не понимаю ошибки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите функцию, которая вычисляет по заданному в десятичной системе счисления числу N количество единиц в двоичной записи этого числа (0 <= N <= 10^6)

```
def numberOfOnes(N):
a = 0
while N > 0: 
    if N % 2 == 1:
        a += 1
    else: 
        break
return a         

N = int(input())
k = numberOfOnes(N)
print(k)
```

Comment: какой ошибки? В вопросе никакая ошибка не указана

Comment: возьми карандаш, лист бумаги и пройдись по своему коду для любого числа. А лучше для нескольких. Тогда поймешь, в чем ошибка

Comment: Runtime error и нет вывода

Comment: А само N в цикле кто будет менять - Пушкин?

Comment: А в чем смысл N менять, не могу понять

Comment: Дык оно не меняется - вот у тебя и фигачит цикл без остановки.

Comment: @Akina на четных останавливается

Comment: @Эникейщик Угу, если ввести чётное, сразу вернёт ноль. А если нечётное - повесится.

Comment: break непонятно зачем, ломает весь цикл

Comment: Подскажите что нужно дописать в коде, пожалуйста

Comment: Сначала продумай алгоритм, а потом уже пиши код. Если писать наугад, то редко получается правильно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
def numberOfOnes(N):
  a = 0
  while N > 0: 
    a += N % 2
    N //= 2
  return a
```

PS. Для отрицательных всегда возвращает ноль, есссно.

Answer (score 4):

Так, для разнообразия, хотя это читерство, конечно )

```
def numberOfOnes(N):
    return bin(N).count('1')
```

Comment: По-моему, это не читерство, это - уровень владения встроенным возможностями python-а...

Comment: @Jack_oS Ну вдруг там задание именно на арифметику всякую было

Answer (score 3):

Вот самый короткий вариант:

```
N = int(input())
f"{N:b}".count('1')
```

Если версия питона ещё не поддерживает `f""`,то так:

```
"{:b}".format(N).count('1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива второму ответу

```py
def numberOfOnes(N):
    result = 0
    massiv = list(bin(N))
    massiv = massiv[2:]
    for i in massiv:
        if i == "1":
            result += 1
    return result


N = int(input())
k = numberOfOnes(N)
print(k)
```

Comment: Вот уж воистину - "зачем просто, если можно сложно"? :)

Comment: Думал что код будет меньше но походу запутался :) (Запутался, из-за того что хотел по максимум уменьшить код)

Comment: Но за идею с `bin(N)` спасибо )

Comment: Моя идея из первых, но судя по стрелочкам она бесполезна)